# Object is persisted without calling save() method

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

First I get a **persistent** object(instance A) from DB, then I **set** value to a field. I **call** persistent object from DB again(instance B). Unexpectedly the loaded object(instance B) **has** the value I set to instance A. Even I didn't call any save() method.

What is the reason behind this **unexpected** behavior and how can I fix it ?

Here is the test failing:

```
@RunWith( SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class )
@ContextConfiguration( locations = { "/webapp-beans.xml" } )
@Transactional
public class HibernatePersistentTest extends TestCase
{
    @Autowired
    CompanyDAO companyDAO;

    @Test
    public void persisting_setAValueAndOnlyCallGet_fieldValueDoesNotChange()
    {
        // GIVEN
        // persist new Company
        Company company = new Company();
        company.setIsDeleted( YesNoType.NO );
        company.setName( "A" );
        companyDAO.getHibernateTemplate().saveOrUpdate( company );

        // assert "object persisted properly"
        Company companyA = (Company) companyDAO.getHibernateTemplate().get( Company.class, company.getId() );
        assertEquals( "Field value changed", "A", companyA.getName() );

        // WHEN set name B and call get()
        company.setName( "B" );
        Company companyB = (Company) companyDAO.getHibernateTemplate().get( Company.class, company.getId() );

        // THEN name should be still A
        assertEquals( "Field value changed", "A", companyB.getName() );
    }
}
```

My hibernate configuration:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClass"> <value>oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</value></property>
    <property name="jdbcUrl"><value>${jdbc.url}</value></property>
    <property name="user"><value>${jdbc.encusername}</value></property>
    <property name="password"><value>${jdbc.encpassword}</value></property>
    <property name="initialPoolSize"><value>10</value></property>
    <property name="minPoolSize"><value>10</value></property>
    <property name="maxPoolSize"><value>100</value></property>
    <property name="maxStatements"><value>0</value></property>
    <property name="preferredTestQuery"><value>SELECT 1 FROM DUAL</value></property>
    <property name="idleConnectionTestPeriod"><value>300</value></property>
    <property name="checkoutTimeout"><value>10000</value></property>
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.use_outer_join">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">0</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.use_streams_for_binary">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connnection.charSet">UTF8</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.defaultNChar">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.transaction.flush_before_completion">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.default_batch_fetch_size">16</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</prop>
            <prop key="connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider</prop>
            <prop key="current_session_context_class">thread</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.default_schema">${schema}</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    <property name="packagesToScan">
        <list merge="true">
            <value>com/pegasus/data/entity</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is completely expected behavior.

Inside a given session, only one instance of a given entity exists. It's stored in the first-level cache that is associated with the session. Any query you execute inside this session that returns an entity of the same type, with the same ID, will return this unique entity instance stored in the cache. And any change you make to this entity will be made persistent automatically (unless you change the flush mode).

My guess is that your test is transactional, and thus everything inside the test is executing inside a single session, hence the behavior you're seeing.

If your test is not transactional, and each DAO call is made inside a new transaction, then you should see the behavior you're expecting.

Comment: You're absolutely right - [here is the relevant doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.5.RELEASE/reference/testing.html#testing-tx). To quote _By default, the framework will create and roll back a transaction for each test_.

Comment: How do I make my test not be transactional? After hours of searching, it's impossible. If the code being tested is wrong and does not save the changes into the database, my unit test doesn't realise it. The tests searches the entity in the database and the changes are saved. This is not the behaviour I want for a unit test.

Answer (score 0):

This behaviour is just like hibernate is meant to behave: two `get()`-calls using the same id should return the same object-instance - and so the previous change will still be reflected in that instance.

This behaviour is required by the JPA-spec:

> The value of its primary key uniquely identifies an entity instance
>   within a persistence context and to EntityManager operations as
>   described in Chapter 3, “Entity Operations”.